# Code example of Spring AMQP + ActiveMQ without reliance on JMS API

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

Is there any working source code example of Spring AMQP + ActiveMQ (sender + receiver) without any reliance on the JMS API?

Note: The reason for this question is because Spring already [lists JMS as a deprecated transport protocol for remoting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#remoting) (only AMQP and web-service calls are still actively supported).

Comment: To be clear, JMS is not deprecated in general. It's just deprecated for "remoting." Are you wanting to use "remoting" or just messaging?

Comment: spring-amqp has nothing to do with ActiveMQ, it is a library for RabbitMQ.

Comment: Spring's tools here are misleading. It is important to note that RabbitMQ's protoocl "AMQP 0.9.x" isn't the same as the standards-based AMQP. ActiveMQ supports the standards-based AMQP.

Comment: @JustinBertram I want to use remoting. I would like to know if it's possible to do remoting with ActiveQM via amqp, without using JMS API which is flagged as deprecated for remoting

Comment: @GaryRussell there's a library called activemq-amqp. any idea if that can by used in combination with AmqpProxyFactoryBean ? (activeqm supports amqp 1.0 ...I would like to use that in combination with AmqpProxyFactoryBean)

Comment: It's hard to say since you don't really explain where the `activemq-amqp` "library" comes from, but it's plausible you're talking about [ActiveMQ's own `activemq-amqp` module](https://github.com/apache/activemq/tree/master/activemq-amqp) which is used by the broker to support AMQP 1.0. This has no use outside the broker. It's not a client that can be integrated with Spring.

Comment: No, the `AmqpProxyFactoryBean` only works with RabbitMQ (amqp 0.9.1). It, too, will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted on the [Spring AMQP GitHub project page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp):

> This project provides support for using Spring and Java with [AMQP 0.9.1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html), and in particular RabbitMQ.

ActiveMQ (both classic and Artemis) supports AMQP 1.0 (standardized by ISO) and *not* 0.9.1 (not standardized). Therefore you **can't** use Spring AMQP with ActiveMQ. The Spring AMQP project is really only useful for integrating with RabbitMQ.